# How to pass binding(two way data binding) from HTML file to Typescript file in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-databinding

let me simplify the specific issue:

html looks like:

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd"></div>
```

i have an array

```
 TrueFalseOptions = [
        {key: 'true' , value: 'true'},
        {key: 'false' , value: 'false'}
    ];
```

i am setting the innerhtml of a div as follows in my ts file:

```
this.htmltoAdd = "<label>Required</label><select class='form-control'> <option *ngFor='let c of {{TrueFalseOptions}}' [ngValue]='{{c.value}}'>c.key</option></select>";
```

if i don't use the pipe - i do not see anything from the above statement. If i use a pipe as described below:

```
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class Safe {
    constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

    transform(style) {
         return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
    }
}
```

then i can see the select drop down but the binding is missing still.

What could be the issue in this?

Comment: Better way would be to move html from showHtml() to template and use *ngIf ="showRestOfForm"directive on it. In showHtml() you just set variable showRestOfForm to true.

Answer (score 0):

There are some core things wrong with this approach:

1. You cannot use innerHTML and expect that the bindings will work (which simply means that the angular syntax wont work. (no components, directives will be initialized)
2. You should not ever touch the DOM directly like you do in that component (you should try and forget `document.getElementById` and similar functions which are directly manipulating the DOM

To answer your question: What you actually need to do, is to put that html that is in the class into the template, and wrap it in a `<div *ngIf="ele.Required"/>`. Whenever that Required attribute is true, this div will be shown.

P.S. If you ever use innerHTML to add static content between, you can bind it directly like: `<div [innerHTML]="theStringVariable"></div>`

Comment: Hi Denko, I think my question is not so understandable what I want to say. So I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Read my answer again.. the bindings wont work using innerHTML